# Convert 3D coordinates to orthographic scene without opposite direction duplicity

Tags: three.js

I have a function which convert 3D position of object (`v`)  to relative coords towards canvas dimensions, and I project this position to second scene with orthographic camera to make a simple HUD.

Works as expected, but this create the same positions in opposite direction from camera. How to avoid to calculate coords in opposite direction again?

```
var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(...);

var scene = net THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(...);

var ortho_scene = net THREE.Scene();
var ortho_camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(...);

function normalize(val, min, max) { 
    // clip a number to range between -1 and 1 
    // to keep sprite always in the screen (to screen border)
    return Math.min(Math.max(val,min),max); 
}


function toScreenPosition(v, camera) {

  var vector = new THREE.Vector3().copy(v).project(camera);

  var x = normalize(vector.x, -1, 1)*(SCREEN_WIDTH*0.5);
  var y = normalize(vector.y, -1, 1)*(SCREEN_HEIGHT*0.5);

  sprite.position.set( x, y, 0 );   


    // sets the 'sprite' in 'ortho_scene' corectly between 'ortho_camera' 
    // and 'v', but when I rotate camera to 180°, the 'vector' will  be again 
    // vector.x < 1 AND vector.x > -1 
    // and will be rendered again on 'ortho_scene' on opposite direction. 
    // How to avoid that?

    // one idea, but it is not a solution
    if(new THREE.Vector2(vector.x,vector.y).angle() < Math.PI*0.5) {
       //keep sprite
       sprite.visible = true;
    } else {
       //hide sprite
       sprite.visible = false;
    }    


 }
```

I can test the angle between a perspective camera and point is > than Math.PI/2

but i need to canvas always pointing to the object in every camera angle.

Comment: What do you mean orthographic scene? There is no such thing, there's only orthographic camera.

Comment: yes i mean another scene named "orthographic" with orthographic camera, for creating standard HUD approach, i updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if source object's position is within PerspectiveCamera frustum:

```
checkCameraFrustum(camera, position) {
    const frustum = new THREE.Frustum();
    const matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().multiplyMatrices(camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse);
    frustum.setFromProjectionMatrix(matrix);
    return frustum.containsPoint(position);
},
```

Regarding **your example**:

```
var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(...);

var scene = net THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(...);

var ortho_scene = net THREE.Scene();
var ortho_camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(...);

function normalize(val, min, max) { 
    // clip a number to range between -1 and 1 
    // to keep sprite always in the screen (to screen border)
    return Math.min(Math.max(val,min),max); 
}

function checkCameraFrustum(v, camera) {
    const frustum = new THREE.Frustum();
    const matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().multiplyMatrices(camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse);
    frustum.setFromProjectionMatrix(matrix);
    return frustum.containsPoint(v);
}

function toScreenPosition(v, camera) {

  var vector = new THREE.Vector3().copy(v).project(camera);

  var x = normalize(vector.x, -1, 1)*(SCREEN_WIDTH*0.5);
  var y = normalize(vector.y, -1, 1)*(SCREEN_HEIGHT*0.5);

  sprite.position.set( x, y, 0 );   

  // show if v is within perspective camera frustum
  if (checkCameraFrustum(v, camera)) {
    sprite.visible = true;
  } else {
    sprite.visible = false;
  }
}
```